# Backbone.js & Handlebars.js to create a relative URL

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

In flask, to create a url I use `{{ url_for('login') }}` in the template (Jinja2) and it returns whatever the url is associated the name `login` (for example `/auth/login/`). How do I do this in Handlebars.js and Backbone.js? Is it already implemented?

What I want to achieve:
`{{#urlfor}}loginRoute{{/urlfor}}`
and for that to return: 
`/auth/login`.

My routes:

```
routes: {
    '': 'indexRoute',
    'auth/login': 'loginRoute'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot make sense of why you would be wanting to do this. All you would be doing is creating a [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) helper for finding and returning the name of a key of some Object that holds some value:

The helper would be simple enough:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('urlfor', function (value) {
    for (var key in routes) {
        if (routes.hasOwnProperty(key) && routes[key] === value) {
            return key;
        }
    }
    return null;
});
```

(This assumes, of course, that the helper has access to `routes` in its lexical scope.)

You would use this helper in a template in the following way:

```
<script id="Template" type="text/template">
    <p>The URL for loginRoute is {{urlfor 'loginRoute'}}</p>
</script>
```

However, it seems to me that it would make more sense to forego the helper and instead do this computation before executing your template function and simply pass the value as a parameter:

```
template({ loginUrl: getUrlFor('loginRoute') });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! FYI, it's so then if I change the route, I don't have to update all urls.